# Coin probability problem

Tags: probability

I tag these questions as homework, as they are older exam questions and every year

Can you try to solve/explain how to solve with a method some of these?

If something is answered in an old post please post the link.

---

**1. We toss a fair coin until we get either two heads either two tails. If the probability getting head is $p$, find the expected number or tosses**

Important update: We assume that we stop after $2$ **consecutive** rolls that bring the same result(e.g. HTHTHTHTHTHTHTHH,THTHTHTHTT). The given probability is for getting ONE head.

---

**To community**: I'm familiar with many terms of probability theory so with a good analysis I think I might understand your answers.

Reminder:Their diffictulty may seem easy to medium but not everyone is great at this.

Comment: It wouldn't be a fair one if we know the probability :D

Comment: You mean 2 consecutive heads or tails?

Comment: Yes I try to emphasize it (one of them can happen: if we get two consecutive yes). I had the same question but i guess they... assumed it....

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
X&:= \# \text{ tosses required} \\
\Pr(X\geq 1) &= 1 \\
(\forall n\geq 1) \hspace{20pt}\Pr(X\geq n+1) &= \Pr(\underbrace{HTHT\cdots HT}_{n \text{ times}}) + \Pr(THTH\cdots TH) \\
&= \begin{cases}
2[p(1-p)]^{n/2}, &n \text{ even}\\
[p(1-p)]^{(n-1)/2}, &n \text{ odd}
\end{cases}\\\\
\implies E[X] &= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \Pr(X\geq i) \\
&= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Pr(X\geq 2n) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Pr(X\geq 2n+1) \\
&= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Pr(X\geq (2n-1)+1) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Pr(X\geq (2n)+1) \\
&= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty [p(1-p)]^{n-1} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2[p(1-p)]^{n} \\
&= 1 + 1+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty [p(1-p)]^{n} + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty [p(1-p)]^{n} \\
&= 2+ 3\sum_{n=1}^\infty [p(1-p)]^{n}\\
&= 2+ \frac {3p(1-p)} {1-p(1-p)} \\
&= \frac {3} {1-p(1-p)} -1 \\
\end{align}

I've assumed independence. I might have made an algebraic error somewhere, but a sanity check is to notice that $\displaystyle{ \lim_{p\to 0}E[X] = \lim_{p\to 1}E[X] = 2}$, which is to be expected (mind the pun). Also, the result is symmetrical around $p=1/2$.

Comment: +1 But I do wish you had used $N$ or $X$ or something other than $T$ to denote the number of tosses required so as to avoid confusion with the $T$ in $HT$ etc.

Comment: Mmmm, fair point. Updating...

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ denote the number of tosses needed to get a $HH$ or a $TT$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
P\{X > 0\} &= 1\\
P\{X > 1\} &= 1\\
P\{X > 2\} &= P\{HT\} + P\{TH\} = 2p(1-p)\\
P\{X > 3\} &= P\{HTH\} + P\{THT\} = p^2(1-p) + (1-p)^2p = p(1-p)\\
P\{X > 4\} &= P\{HTHT\} + P\{THTH\} = 2p^2(1-p)^2\\
\vdots\qquad &= \qquad \vdots\\
P\{X = 2k\} &= P\{HTHT\cdots HT\} + P\{THTH\cdots TH\} = 2p^k(1-p)^k\\
P\{X = 2k+1\} &= P\{HTHT\cdots HTH\} + P\{THTH\cdots THT\}=p^{k+1}(1-p)^k+p^k(1-p)^{k+1}\\
&= p^k(1-p)^k\\
\vdots\qquad &= \qquad \vdots
\end{align}$$
So, since $E[X] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P\{X > k\}$ we have that
$$\begin{align}
E[X] &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty P\{X > k\}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2[p(1-p)]^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty [p(1-p)]^{n}\\
&= \frac{2}{1-p(1-p)} + \frac{p(1-p)}{1-p(1-p)}\\
&= \frac{2+p-p^2}{1-p + p^2}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at your possibilities
$$HH,TT,HTH,HTT,THT,THH$$
Let $T$ denote the random variable denoting the number of times the coin has to be tossed to get the desired result.
$$P(T=2)=p^2+(1-p)^2$$
$$P(T=3)=2p^2(1-p)+2(1-p)^2p$$
Then the expected number of tosses is
$$2(p^2+(1-p)^2)+6p(1-p)=2(1+p-p^2)$$

Comment: Aren't there more possibilities? Like: HTHTHTHTHTHH or THTHTT?
I lost you when you entered Bernouli mode :) what do you use for n and k?

Comment: You never mentioned two consecutive heads or tails!

Comment: They don't mention it. They think it's "a given" (reminder: this is an exam question... dear god ;) ). It was in the comment section, I will add it to the question as well.

Comment: If you the requirement is 2 consecutive heads or tails then I am providing another answer.

Comment: Yes that's the requirement

Answer (score -1):

$$P(T=2k)=p^{k+1}(1-p)^{k-1}+p^{k-1}(1-p)^{k+1}=\{p(1-p)\}^{k-1}$$
for events $HTHTHT\cdots HTHH~\text{and}~~THTHTH\cdots THTT$
$$P(T=2k+1)=(1-p)^{k}p^{k+1}+(1-p)^{k+1}p^k=\{p(1-p)\}^k$$
for events $THTHTH\cdots THTHH$ and $HTHTHT\cdots HTHTT$

Given the probabilities calculate the expectation of $T$.

Comment: Could you explain why $P(T=2k)$ is given by your expression and **not** $[p(1-p)]^{k-1}(p^2 + (1-p)^2)$? Your expression accounts for the results of $2k-2$ tosses only, not $2k$ tosses. Also, some hints on how to go about calculating the expectation once the probabilities have been determined would be helpful; there is a series to be summed, and how to calculate the sum is something that beginners have a great deal of difficulty with.

Comment: for $T=2k$ we must get one of the two outcomes $HTHTHT\cdots HTHH$ or $THTHTH\cdots THTT$. Therefore we can get only two ordered sequences of heads and tails. The first event has $T$ occuring in $k-1$ tosses and $H$ occuring in $k+1$ tosses, hence probability of first event is $p^{k+1}(1-p)^{k-1}$. Similarly probability for the second event is $p^{k-1}(1-p)^{k+1}$. Adding we get $p^{k-1}(1-p)^{k-1}(p+(1-p))=\{p(1-p)\}^{k-1}$

Comment: Errrr  no.  How about multiplying out the left side of the last equation in your response and showing that it actually equals $p^{k+1}(1-p)^{k-1}+p^{k-1}(1-p)^{k+1}$? **I** get it to work out to be $p^k(1-p)^{k+1}+p^{k-1}(1-p)^k$ but then, I have been known to be wrong about such things before.